# How to prove rigorously $L[\delta(t-a)] = e^{-as}$?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory

In engineering mathematics (cf. Kreyszig, Ch. 6) the usaual way to prove the equality 
$$
L[\delta(t-a)]=e^{-as}
$$
is as follows:

1. definition : $\delta(t-a) = \lim g_m (t) $ (defined pointwise) where $g_m (t)$ is $m$ on $a \leq t \leq a + 1/m$ and otherwise $0$.
2. Then using Lhopital, we prove
   $$
   \lim_{m \to \infty} L[g_m(t)] = e^{-as}
   $$ 
   and regard this as a proof of the above equality.

But in measure theoretic sense, $L[\delta(t-a)]$ is just $0$ as $\delta$ is $0$ a.e.

And in this case I can neither use DCT or MCT (or what) to insert $\lim$ into the inside of the integral.

So then is it actually wrong equality?

(Here, $L$ is the usual Laplace transform defined by 
$$
L[f](s) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-as} f(t) dt 
$$

Comment: It also depends on what definition of $\delta$ you accept as rigorous. Those range from intuitive to more or less obscure limit approximations to the theory of distributions (linear form acting on suitable test functions).